# How to combine StringParser with ParserT in Purescript?

Tags: parsing, types, functional-programming, purescript

How can I combine functions from both modules:

```
import Text.Parsing.Parser.String (noneOf)
import Text.Parsing.StringParser.Combinators (many)
```

For my parser `userInput`:

```
userInput :: Parser String
userInput = many (noneOf ['\t', '\n'])
```

Purescript complains that

```
Cannot unify type
  Text.Parsing.Parser.ParserT Prim.String _0
with type
  Text.Parsing.StringParser.Parser
```

Documentation on [StringParser](http://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-string-parsers/0.5.0/docs/Text.Parsing.StringParser#d:Parser) and [ParserT](http://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-parsing/0.4.0/docs/Text.Parsing.Parser#d:ParserT).

Comment: The two libraries are separate and not supposed to be compatible. `string-parsers` uses a CPS'd representation, and `parsing` does not, so it's not necessarily simple to adapt one in terms of the other, but it should be possible, by unwrapping the data constructor of each, and putting the pieces together.

Comment: I guess in my case, a custom implementation of `noneOf` for StringParser will suffice.